# How to query filter many-to-many field in flask

Tags: python, flask

My input in postman is :

```
{
  "job_type": [
            1,
            2
        ]
}
```

I have to query filter these values with Model. and append to the list.

```
 job_type = request.json.get('job_type',None)
            if job_type:
                for types in job_type:
                    conditions.append(JobPost.jobtype == types)
```

anyway this is not working.
I'm new to the flask.

models.py

```
class JobPost(db.Model):
    id = db. Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    jobtype = db.relationship('JobType', secondary=type_groups,back_populates='jobpost')
```

Comment: could you describe what you trying to do? and also your syntax of `"job_type": [
        1,
        2
    ]` is incorrect. are you trying to define dictionary?

Comment: I want to filter the query and append to the variable 'conditions' which is a list.{ "job_type": [ 1, 2 ] } is the foreign key IDs of the jobtype model.

Comment: Not familiar with Flask, but you may try `conditions.append(JobPost.jobtype.id == types)` if `1` and `2` are values of `id` column.

Comment: It was done with join method.